# Amount of product with the same category at checkout

Tags: php, magento

I need to build a rule within the checkout magento where the amount of protudos belonging to category A must be 2 times that of B. gateroria products

In my thinking logically, have to get the amount of products from the same category and compare.

I managed to find the product category but individually. Thus the hard work, I saw that there are filters that can be applied to simplify this search. Even exist?

```
<?php
include 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
Mage::app(); // Mage_Core_Model_App
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
$quote = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getQuote();
echo count($quote->getItemsCollection());
foreach ($quote->getItemsCollection() as $item){
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getId());
    $cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
    foreach ($cats as $category_id) {
        $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id) ;
        echo $_cat->getName();
    }
}
?>
```